# autofit excel column width using spreadsheet gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the Ruby Spreadsheet gem to export data from a rails app to excel, is there a way to get the size of a columns adjust to the size of the content automatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not that I know of. I've had to do it manually by keeping track of the lengths of the strings in each column and then taking the max length and adding a couple more units to it, then setting the width of the column to that calculated value.

```
account_name_lengths = []
# generate each row
accounts.each do |account|
  account_name_lengths << account.name.length

  # add to sheet here
end

sheet.column(0).width = account_name_lengths.max + 5
```

Comment: Thanks Cody for this.

Answer (score 4):

For auti-fit all columns

```
def auto_fit(sheet)
  (0...sheet.column_count).each do |col_idx|
    column = sheet.column(col_idx)
    column.width = column.each_with_index.map do |cell, row|
      chars = cell.present? ? cell.to_s.strip.split('').count + 4 : 1
      ratio = sheet.row(row).format(col_idx).font.size / 10
      (chars * ratio).round
    end.max
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you! You helped me to implement it in my gem https://github.com/kalashnikovisme/xls-exporter and a little article about it https://medium.com/@kalashnikovisme/ruby-excel-autofit-cell-content-c1cd1e329706